# Error in Torchinductor Root [Pytorch] when calling model.predict in Keras [Eq and Mod not found]

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

I have come to run a model.predict feature on a saved Keras model which is now generating a new error. A few days prior this error wasn't being shown, and the predict function was working as expected. I am somewhat new to debugging such errors, so please let me know if there is anyone who could assist, or has had the same error.

I am using Torch as the backend here as I am using Torch native dataloaders for audio processing.

`os.environ\["KERAS_BACKEND"\] = "torch"`

Using Google Colab Pro +

**Versions**
Keras = 3.0.0
Torch = 2.1.0+cu121

**Error generated**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0d795d6b2cbf> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 test_features, test_labels = next(iter(validate_dataloader))
      6 
----> 7 y_pred = model_best.predict(test_features,
      8                             verbose=1)
      9 y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred,

15 frames
/tmp/torchinductor_root/qd/cqdzpa2r5c6xpjg3pz5uzw6gd2ei77hra7t23ifc5xmgzabth2fb.py in call(args)
     29     s1 = arg1_1
     30     assert_size_stride(arg2_1, (32, 1376, s0, s1), (1376*s0*s1, 1, 1376*s1, 1376))
---> 31     return (Eq(((-Mod(s1 - 1, 3))//2) + 1, ((3 - Mod(s1 - 1, 3))//2)), Eq(((-Mod(s0 - 1, 3))//2) + 1, ((3 - Mod(s0 - 1, 3))//2)), 1 + (((-1)*(((-1) + s1) % 3)) // 2), ((3 + ((-1)*(((-1) ...
     32 
     33 

NameError: Exception encountered when calling MaxPooling2D.call().

name 'Eq' is not defined

Arguments received by MaxPooling2D.call():
  • inputs=torch.Tensor(shape=torch.Size([32, 16, 32, 1376]), dtype=float32)
```

**Torch Inductor root file taken from the final frame.**

```
from ctypes import c_void_p, c_long
import torch
import math
import random
import os
import tempfile
from math import inf, nan
from torch._inductor.hooks import run_intermediate_hooks
from torch._inductor.utils import maybe_profile

from torch import empty_strided, device
from torch._inductor.codecache import AsyncCompile
from torch._inductor.select_algorithm import extern_kernels

aten = torch.ops.aten
assert_size_stride = torch._C._dynamo.guards.assert_size_stride
reinterpret_tensor = torch.ops.inductor._reinterpret_tensor
async_compile = AsyncCompile()


async_compile.wait(globals())
del async_compile

def call(args):
    arg0_1, arg1_1, arg2_1 = args
    args.clear()
    s0 = arg0_1
    s1 = arg1_1
    assert_size_stride(arg2_1, (32, 1376, s0, s1), (1376*s0*s1, 1, 1376*s1, 1376))
    return (Eq(((-Mod(s1 - 1, 3))//2) + 1, ((3 - Mod(s1 - 1, 3))//2)), Eq(((-Mod(s0 - 1, 3))//2) + 1, ((3 - Mod(s0 - 1, 3))//2)), 1 + (((-1)*(((-1) + s1) % 3)) // 2), ((3 + ((-1)*(((-1) + s1) % 3))) // 2), 1 + (((-1)*(((-1) + s0) % 3)) // 2), ((3 + ((-1)*(((-1) + s0) % 3))) // 2), )


def benchmark_compiled_module(times=10, repeat=10):
    from torch._dynamo.testing import rand_strided
    from torch._inductor.utils import print_performance
    arg0_1 = 16
    arg1_1 = 32
    arg2_1 = rand_strided((32, 1376, 16, 32), (704512, 1, 44032, 1376), device='cpu', dtype=torch.float32)
    return print_performance(lambda: call([arg0_1, arg1_1, arg2_1]), times=times, repeat=repeat)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from torch._inductor.wrapper_benchmark import compiled_module_main
    compiled_module_main('None', benchmark_compiled_module)
```

Use Keras' model.predict function to predict. I am expecting the batched predictions to come through as achieved a few days before (nothing has changed in the code), I simply disconnected from the runtime in Google Colab.